# Task Details Form - Use for Current, Actual and Baseline radio buttons

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I'm slowly learning Project but can't seem to find the answer especially to the different uses or meanings for the Current and Actual buttons on the Task>Details form.
Could someone explain them to me please?

many thanks, Laurence

Comment: There are current, actual and baseline fields in Project, but no radio buttons with this label in the Task Details form in my version. Could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Those three radio buttons determine which start and finish dates are being depicted on the Task Details Form.
When you first schedule a project, all dates in the "Start" and "Finish" columns are Current Dates.  Assuming automatic scheduling, these dates are computed according to logic and other constraints.  Before starting execution, you should save a snapshot of these dates as a Baseline for future comparison.  During project execution, Actual dates are entered.  These may be different then the logic-driven (Current) dates and will over-write the Current dates when entered.  Actual dates are interlocked with schedule progress (i.e. %complete).